# Argument labels do not match any available overloads error when updating to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

When converting Swift syntax to the latest version I am getting the error:

```
Argument labels '(_:, fromDate:)' do not match any available overloads
```

At the following line:

```
let components = calendar.components(componentOptions, fromDate: NSDate())
```

For reference, here is the line in context of other constants/variables.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let componentOptions:NSCalendar.Unit = .weekday
        let components = calendar.components(componentOptions, fromDate: NSDate())
        var weekday = components.weekday

        let days = ["S", "S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F"]
```

What exactly is my error and how can I solve it? Seems like a simple fix, I just can't figure out.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

In the line:

```
let components = calendar.components(componentOptions, fromDate: NSDate())
```

I changed `fromDate` to `from` and after a series of Xcode recommended changes I got:

`let components = calendar.dateComponents(componentOptions, from: NSDate() as Date)`

but am now getting the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSCalendar.Unit' to expected argument type 'Set<Calendar.Component>'
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1414841-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these lines:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday], from: Date())
```